# Numba fails to compile np.select based function in nopython mode

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, numba, jit

I am attempting to compile what is effectively a piecewise function using `numba.njit`. The Python function is defined as follows, using Numpy:

(for anyone interested in the `Sympy` origins of this issue, see the Notes below.)

**Minimal Example**

```
from numpy import select, less, nan
def f(t):
    condlist = [less(t, 5), less(t, 15), less(t, 20), True]
    choicelist = [1, 0, 1, 0]
    return select(condlist, choicelist, default=nan)
```

See below for confirmation that this function works in Python.

**The Issue: However, Numba fails to JIT this function in `nopython` mode:**

```
from numba import njit
jit_f = njit(f)

x = np.linspace(0, 50, 500)
jit_f(x)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [86], in <cell line: 5>()
      2 jit_f = njit(f)
      4 x = np.linspace(0,50,500)
----> 5 jit_f(x)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py:468, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    464         msg = (f"{str(e).rstrip()} \n\nThis error may have been caused "
    465                f"by the following argument(s):\n{args_str}\n")
    466         e.patch_message(msg)
--> 468     error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    469 except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    470     # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info
    471     error_rewrite(e, 'unsupported_error')

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py:409, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args.<locals>.error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    407     raise e
    408 else:
--> 409     raise e.with_traceback(None)

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<function select at 0x105f4d310>) found for signature:
 
 >>> select(LiteralList((array(bool, 1d, C), array(bool, 1d, C), array(bool, 1d, C), Literal[bool](True))), list(int64)<iv=[1, 0, 1, 0]>, default=float64)
 
There are 2 candidate implementations:
      - Of which 1 did not match due to:
      Overload in function 'np_select': File: numba/np/arraymath.py: Line 4358.
        With argument(s): '(Poison<LiteralList((array(bool, 1d, C), array(bool, 1d, C), array(bool, 1d, C), Literal[bool](True)))>, list(int64)<iv=None>, default=float64)':
       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         TypingError: Poison type used in arguments; got Poison<LiteralList((array(bool, 1d, C), array(bool, 1d, C), array(bool, 1d, C), Literal[bool](True)))>
  raised from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/types/functions.py:236
      - Of which 1 did not match due to:
      Overload in function 'np_select': File: numba/np/arraymath.py: Line 4358.
        With argument(s): '(LiteralList((array(bool, 1d, C), array(bool, 1d, C), array(bool, 1d, C), Literal[bool](True))), list(int64)<iv=[1, 0, 1, 0]>, default=float64)':
       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         NumbaTypeError: condlist must be a List or a Tuple
  raised from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/np/arraymath.py:4375

During: resolving callee type: Function(<function select at 0x105f4d310>)
During: typing of call at /var/folders/dt/q6vbs0g56s70g4p2kyfj4tvh0000gn/T/ipykernel_61924/130570246.py (5)


File "../../../../../../../../../var/folders/dt/q6vbs0g56s70g4p2kyfj4tvh0000gn/T/ipykernel_61924/130570246.py", line 5:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

I'm not a Numba expert, but my feeling is that there is some syntax error. I've played around passing Numpy arrays and different formats of `condlist` and `choicelist`, but no luck so far.

**Other Notes**

The Python function behaves as expected, in this case giving some binary oscillations and then zero:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 50, 500)
plt.plot(x, f(x))
```

[image: output of python func]

For any Sympy aficionados, the overlying problem here is with using Numba to JIT compile a lambda generated via Sympy from `sympy.Piecewise`. A lambda very similar to `f(t)` in the above example can be autogenerated by `sympy.lambdify` on a Piecewise function.

Comment: I'm not surprised that it can't handle a `lambdified` function.  It actually has to have access to the python code; `numba` doesn't just "run a black-box' function "faster".  As for `select`, isn't that something you can write directly with required iterations?  With `numba` you can write iterative code without a time penalty.  Using `numpy` functions in `numba` is just a convenience for the programmers, not essential for performance.

Comment: @hpaulj whether the function is `lambdified` actually doesn't appear to matter. I believe `sympy.lambdify` generates a string and then calls `exec` to create the anonymous function. It is common practice to use `lambdify` to generate `numpy` or `math` based functions from `sympy` expressions. This example shows an example where sympy expressions are used to create an ODE system that is JIT compiled by Numba: https://www.sympy.org/scipy-2017-codegen-tutorial/notebooks/20-ordinary-differential-equations.html.

Comment: @hpaulj Re your point about `select`, the code could be written in other (better) ways but I wanted to get it to work with the default output of `sympy` as the overall project involves algorithmically generated expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numba does not currently implement all Numpy function and the support is sometimes limited. You can find the list of supported functions [in the documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/numpysupported.html). For `np.select`, the documentation states that the support is limited to:

> only using **homogeneous lists** or tuples for the first two arguments, `condlist` and `choicelist`. Additionally, these two arguments can **only contain arrays** (unlike Numpy that also accepts tuples).

The thing is `condlist` is not homogeneous since the 3 first items of the list are arrays while the last is a boolean value. Additionally, `choicelist` contains integers while it must contains arrays.

One solution to fix this problem is to use the following code:

```py
def f(t):
    condlist = [less(t, 5), less(t, 15), less(t, 20), np.full(t.size, True)]
    all_zeros = np.zeros(t.size)
    all_ones = np.ones(t.size)
    choicelist = [all_ones, all_zeros, all_ones, all_zeros]
    return select(condlist, choicelist, default=nan)
```

However, please **do not use this code** as it is inefficient. Indeed, it creates many **temporary arrays** that are slow to create and fill. The code will certainly be memory bound and memory is a scarce resource only slowly improving over the last decades (this is called the *"memory wall"*). Optimizing such code is hard and Numba is not faster than Numpy for that. In fact, Numpy is already quite efficient to do that since it is implemented in C and most function are carefully optimized. Numba is fast when you use loops and avoid creating (useless) temporary arrays. Put it shortly: **Numba likes loops** as opposed to Numpy. Here is a much faster solution:

```py
def f(t):
    result = np.empty(t.size)
    for i in range(t.size):
        result[i] = t[i] < 5 or 15 <= t[i] < 20
    return result
```

Note that using a boolean or a short integer (eg. `int8`) output type should be even faster (floating-point numbers are slow to compute and takes a lot of space in memory).

Comment: Thanks, this clearly answers the question about Numba with the example function given. It sounds like to get my overall use case working (Numba with sympy-generated functions based on `piecewise` operators that contain `seleect` and `less`) will require altering the implementation of `sympy.lambdify` so it generates code that operates within Numba's compatibility constraints.